Why is non-English content apparently allowed on this website?
On one of the posts in the main Q&A site, there is a comment which is written in a foreign language, certainly not in English:

Per the network's global policies, having language-specific sites as exceptions, it should not be allowed (first Q&A on Meta, second Q&A on Meta). I flagged it for attention, but the flag was a) declined, b) done so without any explanation, c) the comment hasn't been translated nor deleted.

Questions, answers, and comments are supposed to be useful for everyone. The network doesn't have a private-message feature implemented for a reason, and comments should not used as a surrogate for non-existing feature. Which on Physics SE means, English or bust.
Why are the moderators allowing otherwise?

I would opt to flag that as 'no longer needed' instead.

The preceding comment has been flagged (by someone else) as "no longer needed," which I find so hilariously self-referential that I've decided to preserve it for a while.

@rob Now, to complete the circle of life, the person who flagged it needs to create new "why was my flag rejected" question, and write a similar whiny rant as me :D

In order to complement the "Not an answer, should be a comment instead" flag on answers, we need a "Not a comment, should be an answer instead" flag on comments.

I have calmed down a lot since posting this, but the negative score still goes down. Have them coming guys, have them coming, pat yourselves on the back right now, you are doing a good job.

Not quite enough, it seems ...  Anyway, in case it makes you feel more relaxed about it, note that votes on Meta don't affect your reputation.

I wasn't the mod who declined the flag; I suspect I'm representing their reasoning, but I haven't spoken with them about it. That particular comment appeared to have been understood by everyone involved in the post, judging by subsequent replies. (Heck, I can only guess at the language, but it looks like something about doing physics at a particular institution in Zagreb; that guess was borne out by other comments in the thread.)
Comments are meant to be transient, and that discussion was a dozen years old, so now all those comments are gone.
To some of you other points:

Why are the moderators allowing otherwise?

As a rule, we don't.  But we don't make a habit of combing ancient posts for incomprehensible snippets, either.  We don't tolerate questions or answers that are completely in non-English languages, and we probably would remove a comment thread that was mostly in a non-English language.  A single sentence in a discussion that stays in English is a different creature.

the flag was a) declined, b) done so without any explanation

We can leave explanations when we approve or decline flags on questions or answers.  But we can't attach explanations to flags on comments.  Old comments just aren't a big deal.

I'm also going to respond to some other things that arose in comments.  I want to make it clear that not all of these issues were raised by the same user.

My issue with this situation is, it is way too easy for you to ruin new user's flag weight. The comments are gone, and the flag is still marked as rejected, tainting the record.

This also really isn't a big deal.  If you have too many flags declined, you might not be able to raise new flags for a few days.  I thought I had remembered that there was a list of users who had hit this limit, and that it was empty.  But instead it appears that there is no record of which users are restricted from raising flags.  Not being able to raise flags doesn't affect other things you might like to do on the site.

I believe that it was the moderator's misjudgment

Perhaps.  I'm not too worried either way about a single comment flag.

And acting upon the flags is the expected behavior

You are a frequent flagger, and somewhere north of 95% of your flags have been marked as helpful.  This "expected behavior" is the norm for you.  This is what healthy flagging looks like.

in less than a month you have flagged 150 things? Do remember that the mods who responded to them are unpaid volunteers.

Our dashboard says that we've handled 800 flags in the last month.  Most of those got handled by the review queues, without  intervention by the diamond moderators.

Three dislikes so far, keep them coming

Votes on Stack Exchange aren't "like/dislike"; they are "useful/not useful."  I frequently like things that are not useful, and vice-versa.


Spoken (or rather written) like someone who understands only English

calm down … Next time, think before posting a condescending comment like that

Your comment is extremely patronizing and judgmental.



To repeat: not all of the quotes in this section are from the same user.  But this fighty stuff isn't okay.  Be polite to each other, or look at some other website for a while.
I think this edited version of the answer addresses the issues raised in the comments, so I've removed them.

Not 100% satisfied with how this was handled and how the stain on my flag weight still remains, but you were quite friendly and helpful, so giving your post a green mark.

@user402514 Shouldn't the stain on the flag weight have aged away by now?

@NorbertSchuch I don't think it ages away at all, the "declined comment flags" counter on my profile shows "3" and I don't think it will ever expire or otherwise go down to "0", it can only go up. What I can do, is do my best to make sure the proportion of helpful-vs-rejected ratio itself gets better over time.

The declined comment count does not ever go down. But any negative consequences of a bad flag age away after a week, as I understand it

@user402514 Indeed, what rob says: Since a policy change several years ago, all what matters is the negative flags in the last 7 days. And all one can see from the outside is your number of helpful flags. No-one can tell whether, and how many, negative flags you had. (To iterate: You are taking this far too seriously.)

@NorbertSchuch Thank you, no worries as right now I have simmered down quite a lot, but yes I was far too serious for such a small thing. Cheers.
